# Why is T not string* when template <typename T> string debug_rep(T *p) is called with debug_rep(&s)

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I'm trying to understand an example from C++ Primer to do with template overloading.

They define two function templates:

`template <typename T> string debug_rep(const T &t) { ... }`

and

`template <typename T> string debug_rep(T *p) { ... }`

The following call is then made:

```
string s("hi");
cout << debug_rep(&s) << endl;
```

The example then goes on to say that both functions generate viable instantiations.

`debug_rep(const string* &) with T bound to string*`

and

`debug_rep(string*) with T bound to string`

Why is `T` not `string*` in the second instantiation when it is in the first?   Won't the compiler deduce the type of `&s` as `string*` and bind this to `T`?  Then `debug_rep(T *p)` would be instantiated as `debug_rep(string **p)`?  I've re-read the chapter a few times but can't find the rule causing this.

Comment: It can't be `debug_rep(string **p)` because you are passing it `string*`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for the reply.  Isn't the instantiation of the function argument a pointer to whatever `T` is though, and here `T` is a `string*`?  This is where I'm getting confused and get `debug_rep(string **p)` from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler sees this template:

```
template <typename T> string debug_rep(T *p)
```

and a call like:

```
debug_rep(&s)
```

the compiler will do its best to match the type of the argument to the type in the function declaration.

Since the type of the argument is `string*`, and the type in the declaration is `T*`, the simplest way to match the declaration is to substitute `string` for `T`.

Similarly, the simplest way to match `string*` to `const T &t` for the other template is to substitute `string*` for `T`, which results in `const string * &`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So as a result of the `deduction' logic the compiler will choose the type of `T` to best fit the function parameter?  What would happen if the function parameter was `T **p`?

Comment: Yes. You can try it out yourself,  but I'm pretty sure it won't match, since there is no way for `string*` to be `T**`.

Comment: The book mentions elsewhere that the only argument conversions that are allowed are const conversions and array/function-to-pointer.  How does that fit into this?

Comment: There's no need for any conversions in this case. Note that `string` is substituted for `T` without any additional conversion. Same thing in the other case.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Those conversions (if necessary) apply on top of the deduction?